# Не находит файл java

Tags: java

Всем привет. Застопорился, помогите, гуру Java.)

```
package test;

public class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node next;

    public Node(int value, Node next){
        this.value = value;
        this.next = next;
    }
}
```

---

```
package test;
import test.*;
public class App0 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Node tail = null;
        for (int k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
            tail = new Node(k, tail); 
        }
        System.out.println(tail.value);
        System.out.println(tail.next.value);
        System.out.println(tail.next.next.value);
        System.out.println(tail.next.next.next.value);
    }
}
```

Такое вот сообщение при компиляции App0 файла:

```
C:\Users\Станислав\Desktop\LinkedList>javac -d classes test/App0.java
test\App0.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
                Node tail = null;
                ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class App0
test\App0.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
                        tail = new Node(k, tail);
                                   ^
  symbol:   class Node
  location: class App0
2 errors
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А как у вас расположены файлы классов? Я попробовал с файлами в одной директории(как и должно быть) и у меня всё отработало без ошибок.

Comment: А у меня почему-то нет

Comment: Какая у Вас версия java? @Vartlok

Comment: java version "1.8.0_51"

Answer (score 1):

Файл с классом `Node` должен называться `Node.java`.

Comment: Он так и называется

Comment: У вас оба файла хранятся в папке test?

Comment: да, в папке test  @pavelip